# Saving the result of a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

When doing a research in mongo shell I often write quite complex queries and want the result to be stored in other collection. I know the way to do it with `.forEach()`:

`db.documents.find(query).forEach(function(d){db.results.insert(d)})`

But it's kind of tedious to write that stuff each time. Is there a cleaner way? I'd like the syntax to be something like `db.documents.find(query).dumpTo('collectionName')`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a solution I'll use: `db.results.insert(db.docs.find(...).toArray())`

There is still too much noise, though.

*UPD*: There is also an option to rewrite `find` using aggregation pipeline. Then you can use [`$out` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are doing your queries from the mongo shell, which allows you to write code in javascript. You can assign the result of queries to a variable:

```
result = db.mycollection.findOne(my_query)
```

And save the result to another collection:

```
db.result.save(result)
```

You might have to remove the _id of the result if you want to append it to the result collection, to prevent a duplicate key error

Edit:

```
db.mycollection.findOne({'_id':db.mycollection.findOne()['_id']})
db.foo.save(db.bar.findOne(...))
```

If you want to save an array, you can write a javascript function. Something like the following should work (I haven't tested it):

```
function save_array(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        db.result.save(arr[i])
    }
}

...

result = db.mycollection.find(...)
save_array(result)
```

If you want the function to be available every time you start mongo shell, you can include it in your `.mongorc.js` file

Comment: Well, but I don't want to use `.forEach` at all. It would be nice if I could do `db.result.save(db.docs.find(...))`, but it says "can't save a DBQuery"

Comment: I think what you tried failed because the inner db.docs.find query returns an array rather than a document. Save can save a document. See the edit.

Comment: thanks, I've already found that `DBQuery` has `.toArray()` method which does what I want.

Comment: i have problems with the save array, I used this method:´
`function save_array(arr) { arr.forEach(element => db.result.save(element)); };`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't built-in functionality to do this in MongoDB.

Other options would be to use [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)/[mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) or [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)/[mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) functionalities.

In both mongoexport and mongodump you can filter the results by adding query options using `--query <JSON>` or `-q <JSON>`.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is using an aggregation operator then the solution is as sample as using the $out.

I created a sample Collection with the name "tester" which contain the following records.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36bfd3d1c88bfa15103b1"), "name" : "bob", "value" : 5, "state" : "b"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36c033d1c88bfa15103b2"), "name" : "bob", "value" : 3, "state" : "a"} 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36c063d1c88bfa15103b3"), "name" : "bob", "value" : 7, "state" : "a"}   

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36c0c3d1c88bfa1a03b4"), "name" : "john", "value" : 2, "state" : "a"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36c103d1c88bfa5103b5"), "name" : "john", "value" : 4, "state" : "b"} 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36c143d1c88bfa15103b"), "name" : "john", "value" : 8, "state" : "b"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb36c163d1c88bfa15103a"), "name" : "john", "value" : 6, "state" : "a"}
```

Now using the aggregate operator I perform a group by and then save the result into a new collection using this magical operator "$out".

```
db.tester.aggregate([{$group:{
                                _id:{name:"$name",state:"$state"},
                                min:{$min:"$value"},
                                max:{$max:"$value"},
                               } },
                       {$out:"tester_max_min"}
                     ])
```

What basically the query is trying to do is, group by name & state and find the min and max values for each individual group, and then save the result into a new collection named "tester_max_min"

```
db.tester_max_min.find();
```

The new collection formed will have the following documents in it :

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "john", "state" : "b" }, "min" : 4, "max" : 8 }

{ "_id" : { "name" : "john", "state" : "a" }, "min" : 2, "max" : 6 }

{ "_id" : { "name" : "bob", "state" : "a" }, "min" : 3, "max" : 7 }

{ "_id" : { "name" : "bob", "state" : "b" }, "min" : 5, "max" : 5 }
```

I still need to explore how helpful can $out is but it works like a charm for any aggregator operator.

Comment: $out will completely replace the original collection if it is pointed to the same collection as the aggregate, so if there is a $match filter everything not matched will be deleted.